# How to make "hostname -i" command to return ip address of a particular network interface device

Tags: linux, hostname

In some Linux hosts it returns IP of the interface **eth0** and in some it returns IP assigned to NIC **eth1** device, and in some machines it returns all the IP assigned to all the network interfaces.

```
$ hostname -i
*192.168.0.58  192.168.0.59  192.168.0.60*
```

How this is happening and how to configure this **hostname** command to return an IP of a particular network interface?

Comment: Can't you use `strace hostname -i` in order to find out where the information is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no option in `hostname` to return the IP of a particular network interface.
Try this:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -Po 'inet \K(\S+)'
```